# Running SAS code on multiple files with DO LOOP and a MACRO

Tags: sas

I am very new to SAS and have received my first work assignment. Basically, I need to pull all of the patient ID's (patid) and procedure code (proc_cd) from multiple SAS files and put it into an excel file.

From my research, I believe I need a MACRO with a do loop that will run this search for all of the files

Below is the code I've put together. Again I'm very new to SAS so any help will be appreciated!

```
libname sas 'P:\H3.2018.DH_StressQuery\dat';
libname optum 'C:\OPTUM Data\Zip5';

data libname.filename;
set libname.filename;


%MACRO LOOP     * I don't know what to put here.
%DO i = 1        %TO 
("zip5_r2018q1.sas7bdat","16.2GB","Sas7bdat","C:\OPTUM 
Data\Zip5\zip5_r2018q1.sas7bdat","11Jul2018:20:07:01"
)

(data sas.query file;
set optum.zip5_m2007q1
    (keep = patid, Proc_Cd);
if Proc_Cd = '94621');

proc  print data= data.query file

%END;

%MEND LOOP;
%LOOP;
```

Comment: How big is your SAS data sets? sometimes it's easier/faster to combine them and run a single proc. In general, I don't recommend macros for new SAS users at all. Doing it with copy/paste at the beginning is better. Otherwise I wrote a short tutorial on converting working code to a macro. See here: https://github.com/statgeek/SAS-Tutorials/blob/master/Turning%20a%20program%20into%20a%20macro.md

Comment: Basically get it working for a single data set and then figure out how to automate/streamline it. Once you have a working program for a single file, post back and we can help with the automation aspect. There's also a SAS studio task that will run a script for every data set specified.

Comment: wow thanks for the quick response! I have quarterly data sheets from 2007-2018. Each file is pretty big, over 12 million rows! I can do it one by one, but figured it would take me almost as much time doing that as trying to figure this out. I got the code working for one dataset (basically everything under the do loop.) Thank you for the tutorial. I will go through that and see if I can figure it out!

Comment: I think that code would have errors, syntax errors at least. Make sure to test it before posting. One thing to keep in mind, for your summaries, store them in data sets with a naming convention, ie _summaryY2018Q1 and then when you need to combine them all for the final report you can do:  `set _summary: ;` which will stack all at once.

Comment: What are the names of the tables ? Are they all in the same library / folder ? Do the data set names follow a consistent naming scheme ? Are there data sets in the library that are not part of this process ? Are there 48 of these 16GB OPTUM data sets on the C:\ drive ? Do you need to also retain any date aspect of the proc_cd ?